# Tag Autocompletion Not Working

Tags: bug, tags, autocomplete

I'm currently trying to post on serverfault. When I try to search for a tag, the dropdown is empty.  I have verified in Chrome debug tools that the call is being made and results are being returned as expected.  I have no console errors. I have disabled all ad blockers and any CSS modifying extensions.

I reproduced the behavior on Stack Overflow and even here, on this post.  The only reason I was able to select BUG is because meta seems to have additional behavior of showing a few tags as soon as you click.  But once I start typing I get the same results as seen in this gif:

[image]

Comment: cross post on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400873/tags-tooltip-not-working

Comment: That may be a duplicate but that question makes unnecessary assumptions and mentions seemingly unrelated things (I don't even know what 10k tools are).  I'm fine with this being closed, just want it known that question seems a bit murky IMO.

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate The other question is _more complete_ by mentioning 10k tools, because the same bug also occurs there.

Comment: I still don't know wtf that is. But since the other question was renamed it makes more sense.